# Cannot destroy the zip context: Can't remove file: No such file or directory in /home/vol10_3/infinityfree.com/if0_35221938/htdocs/index.p

Tags: php, zip

I created a php script which extract data from zip folders then. fetch images from sub folder to parent folder and according to parent folder it rename that images and return single zip file which contains all renamed images.
In my local system its working very well but on infinity free server it showing the below error

> No zip files found in C:\Users\abc\Desktop\ex
>
> No subfolders found in C:\Users\abc\Desktop\ex
>
> Warning: processImages(): Cannot destroy the zip context: Can't remove
> file: No such file or directory in
> /home/vol10_3/infinityfree.com/if0_35221938/htdocs/index.php on line
> 265
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught UnexpectedValueException:
> RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(C:\Users\abc\Desktop\ex):
> Failed to open directory: No such file or directory in
> /home/vol10_3/infinityfree.com/if0_35221938/htdocs/index.php:205 Stack
> trace: #0
> /home/vol10_3/infinityfree.com/if0_35221938/htdocs/index.php(205):
> RecursiveDirectoryIterator->__construct('C:\Users\SUFI\D...') #1
> /home/vol10_3/infinityfree.com/if0_35221938/htdocs/index.php(265):
> createZip('C:\Users\SUFI\D...') #2
> /home/vol10_3/infinityfree.com/if0_35221938/htdocs/index.php(270):
> processImages('C:\Users\SUFI\D...') #3 {main} thrown in
> /home/vol10_3/infinityfree.com/if0_35221938/htdocs/index.php on line
> 205

```
<h2>Bulk upload Image Renamer</h2>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <label for="folderPath">Enter Folder Path:</label>
    <input type="text" id="folderPath" name="folderPath" required>
    <button type="submit">Process Images</button>
    <button type="reset">Reset</button>

</form>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// unzip folders
function unzipSubfolders($folderPath) {
    $zipFiles = glob($folderPath . '/*.zip');

    if (empty($zipFiles)) {
        echo "<p>No zip files found in $folderPath</p>";
    } else {
        foreach ($zipFiles as $zipFile) {
            $folderName = pathinfo($zipFile, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $tempDir = sys_get_temp_dir() . '/' . uniqid('temp_zip_extract_');
            mkdir($tempDir);

            $zip = new ZipArchive;
            if ($zip->open($zipFile) === true) {
                $zip->extractTo($tempDir);
                $zip->close();

                echo "<p>Extracted contents of '$zipFile' to '$tempDir'</p>";

                moveContentsToFolder($tempDir, $folderPath, $folderName);

                unlink($zipFile);
                rmdir($tempDir);
            } else {
                echo "<p>Failed to open zip file: $zipFile</p>";
            }
        }
    }
}

function deleteSecondLevelSubfolders($folderPath) {
    $subfolders = glob($folderPath . '/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);

    foreach ($subfolders as $subfolder) {
        $secondLevelSubfolders = glob($subfolder . '/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);

        if (count($secondLevelSubfolders) > 0) {
            moveContentsToParent($subfolder, $secondLevelSubfolders);

            @rmdir($subfolder);

            echo "<p>child-level subfolder '$subfolder' extracted successfully.</p>";
        }
    }
}
function renameImagesInSubfolders($folderPath) {
    $subfolders = glob($folderPath . '/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);

    if (empty($subfolders)) {
        echo "<p>No subfolders found in $folderPath</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($subfolders as $subfolder) {
            // Check if the subfolder is a zip file
            if (pathinfo($subfolder, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) === 'zip') {
                $zipFolder = $subfolder;
                $tempDir = sys_get_temp_dir() . '/' . uniqid('temp_zip_extract_');
                
                // Extract the contents of the zip file
                $zip = new ZipArchive;
                if ($zip->open($zipFolder) === true) {
                    $zip->extractTo($tempDir);
                    $zip->close();

                    // Rename images in the extracted folder
                    renameImagesInSubfolders($tempDir);

                    // Remove the temporary directory
                    removeDirectory($tempDir);
                } else {
                    echo "<p>Failed to open zip file: $zipFolder</p>";
                }
            } else {
                $subfolderName = basename($subfolder);
                echo "<li>$subfolderName - ";

                $images = glob($subfolder . '/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

                if (empty($images)) {
                    echo "No images found";
                } else {
                    foreach ($images as $image) {
                        $imageName = basename($image);
                        $newImageName = $subfolderName . '_' . $imageName;

                        // Rename the image
                        $newImagePath = $subfolder . '/' . $newImageName;
                        if (rename($image, $newImagePath)) {
                            echo "$newImageName, ";
                        } else {
                            echo "Failed to rename $imageName, ";
                        }
                    }
                }

                echo "</li>";
            }
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}

function createZip($folderPath) {
    // $d=mktime(11, 14, 54, 8, 12, 2014);
    // $zipFileName = 'bulk_upload_images' . date("Y-m-d h:i:sa", $d) . '.zip';
    $zipFileName = 'bulk_upload_images.zip';


    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if ($zip->open($zipFileName, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE) === true) {
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
            new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($folderPath),
            RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
        );

        foreach ($files as $name => $file) {
            if (!$file->isDir()) {
                $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
                $relativePath = basename($filePath);
                $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
            }
        }

        $zip->close();
        // Set permissions for the parent directory
        $parentDirectory = pathinfo($folderPath, PATHINFO_DIRNAME);
        chmod($parentDirectory, 0755);
        echo "<p>Zip file created: $zipFileName</p>";
        echo '<a href="download.php?file=' . urlencode($zipFileName) . '">Download Zip</a>';
    } else {
        echo "<p>Failed to create zip file.</p>";
    }
}
function moveContentsToFolder($source, $destination, $folderName) {
    $files = scandir($source);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..') {
            $sourceFile = $source . '/' . $file;
            $destinationFile = $destination . '/' . $folderName . '/' . $file;

            if (!file_exists($destination . '/' . $folderName)) {
                mkdir($destination . '/' . $folderName, 0777, true);
            }

            rename($sourceFile, $destinationFile);
        }
    }
}
function moveContentsToParent($parentFolder, $subfolders) {
    foreach ($subfolders as $subfolder) {
        $files = glob($subfolder . '/*');

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $newLocation = $parentFolder . '/' . basename($file);
            rename($file, $newLocation);
        }
    }
}
function removeDirectory($dir) {
    $files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.', '..'));
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        (is_dir("$dir/$file")) ? removeDirectory("$dir/$file") : unlink("$dir/$file");
    }
    return rmdir($dir);
}

function processImages($folderPath) {
    unzipSubfolders($folderPath);
    
    deleteSecondLevelSubfolders($folderPath);
    renameImagesInSubfolders($folderPath);
    createZip($folderPath);
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $folderPath = $_POST['folderPath'];
    processImages($folderPath);
}
?>
```

Comment: Which part of `No such file or directory` are you confused about? Do you really think that `C:\Users\abc\Desktop\ex` exists in your hosted server? I doubt that server even runs Windows! In fact I'm certain it doesn't - look at the path names and style given in the error messages. You'd need to enter a valid file path which exists _on the server_ and which the PHP code would have access to read.

Comment: To expand on that, you can't access files on the client's machine from the server, if that's what you wanted to do. They will need to upload the files. Then your script can save them on the server and create a zip from that.

Comment: @ADyson I understand now what's the problem thanks for the support